# Using guzzle to access uri with colon

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I am trying to access resource at this adress `https://companyname.pipedrive.com/v1/deals:(id)?api_token=mytoken` . However when using guzzle I always get this exception

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: deals (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in /var/app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line 186

I think the problem is that colon in url because it works fine without It. I also tried to make the request from postman and everything works fine, so It should be problem with guzzle. Is there a way to make this work ? thanks

Comment: try url encoding your endpoint

Comment: A colon is not a valid character in the URL path according to [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) the browser might dislay a colon in the address bar but that's just because the browser tries to make URLs look pretty. In reality the browsers requests the URL after properly URL encoding it.

Comment: If I try to urlencode just the endpoint It results in 501 method is not implemented

Comment: dumb question why do you have your path named this way?

Comment: https://developers.pipedrive.com/docs/api/v1/#/ I am trying to use this api, to be more specific field selectors

Comment: @user8336738 in the api i don't see any `:(id)` all i see is {id} which you should substitute with the deal id

Comment: @madalinivascu find the `Field selector` paragraph, there is a example `GET https://companydomain.pipedrive.com/v1/deals:(id,title,value,currency)?api_token=YOUR_API_TOKEN`

Comment: Could you please provide the link to the exact pipedrive api part? And show us your php code. Also, which operation are you trying to run: update, delete, get?

Comment: @user8336738, did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @Gustav no, I just got all deals and worked with that in php

Comment: @user8336738 I'm having a similar problem, not solving it either. It's unfortunate cause while testing I discovered that the response time is much shorter when only selecting a few fields for the call.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to replace the colon with the URL encoded equivalent (`%3A`)?

```
https://companyname.pipedrive.com/v1/deals%3A(id)?api_token=mytoken
```

Comment: Yes I tried but it didn't help. For now I just don't use the field selectors.

Comment: It does appear that Guzzle misinterprets the colon. Using the above example I found that the HTTP scheme was set to 'deals' and not https due to the mistreatment of the colon.

Comment: @GregRobson, it's hard to talk without an example. I would advice to use Guzzle's `query` option anyway.

Comment: @AlexeyShokov In the end I dropped the field specification. The JSON payloads are not that large and I'm queuing my jobs anyway.